# Use the access token requested from another end point MS Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to use the an access token requested by another API endpoint to MS Graph to another API endpoint?

Scenario:

1. API Endpoint A requested an access token and receive the access token and store it to the database.
2. API Endpoint B used the access token being stored in the database by
   API EndPoint A.

Comment: Are both of these endpoints MS Graph api?

Comment: If the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

NO!

A token can only correspond to one api. The access token is issued according to the [api audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you want to access, and it is unique! A token can only have one `aud`, and you cannot use multiple scopes to request access tokens. If you need to access other api endpoint, you should obtain a token for each api endpoint separately.

Your idea is indeed feasible for some of the same types of api endpoints. For example, if two identical MS Graph APIs endpoint have the same permissions and user role requirements, you can indeed use API A's access token to call API B, but for security reasons, I don't recommend you to do this.